# Generating ZipFile with List of StringIO Object, CRC Error when Opening the ZipFIle

Tags: python, python-2.7, text-files, stringio, python-zipfile

I am currently facing some difficulty regarding generating Text file with multiple line of text and add it to a ZipFile in memory with Python 2.7.

The code below is able to generate zip file with 4 text file, each file have 1 line of words.

If I modify the code "temp[0].write('first in-memory temp file')" to multiple line string, the zip file generated out will have crc error.

I have tried string escape, but it failed.

May I know what should I do in order to generate the ZipFile filled with MultipleLine-enabled Text File?

```
# coding: utf-8

import StringIO
import zipfile

# This is where my zip will be written
buff = StringIO.StringIO()
# This is my zip file
zip_archive = zipfile.ZipFile(buff, mode='w')

temp = []
for i in range(4):
    # One 'memory file' for each file 
    # I want in my zip archive
    temp.append(StringIO.StringIO())

# Writing something to the files, to be able to
# distinguish them
temp[0].write('first in-memory temp file')
temp[1].write('second in-memory temp file')
temp[2].write('third in-memory temp file')
temp[3].write('fourth in-memory temp file')

for i in range(4):
    # The zipfile module provide the 'writestr' method.
    # First argument is the name you want for the file
    # inside your zip, the second argument is the content
    # of the file, in string format. StringIO provides
    # you with the 'getvalue' method to give you the full
    # content as a string
    zip_archive.writestr('temp'+str(i)+'.txt',
                         temp[i].getvalue())

# Here you finish editing your zip. Now all the information is
# in your buff StringIO object
zip_archive.close()

# You can visualize the structure of the zip with this command
print zip_archive.printdir()

# You can also save the file to disk to check if the method works
with open('test.zip', 'w') as f:
    f.write(buff.getvalue())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are using Windows? Try opening the output zip file in binary mode, i.e.

```
with open('test.zip', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(buff.getvalue())
```

In text mode (the default) Python converts new lines ('\n') to the native line ending sequence, which is `\r\n` in Windows. That will cause the CRC to fail because the CRC is calculated using the data in the `StringIO` buffer, but the data is then altered (`\n` is converted to `\r\n`) when written to the text mode file.